# Can we update +New button on a SharePoint List to new url

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have microsoft form to submit requests which comes and save in a SharePoint List. Users will also have access to the list. Can we make the +New button in the list to redirect to microsoft form.

Can anyone please advise

Comment: Are you using modern experience or classic experience?

Comment: modern experience

Answer (score 0):

You could use ListView Command Set extension. This article is about how to build ListView Command Set extension: [Build your first ListView Command Set extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api).